# Looking for error in my calculations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $ xy' - y = y^2 $

I'm trying to do it using Bernoulli substitution:
$$ z = y^{-1} ;y = z^{-1} ; y^2 = z^{-2} ; y' = -z^{-2}z' $$
$$ - xz' - z = 1 $$
$$ - xz' - z = 0 $$
$$ z' = - \frac{z}{x} $$
$$ \int \frac{1}{z} dz = - \int \frac{1}{x}dx $$
$$ z = \frac{1}{xC(x)} $$
$$z' = \frac{-xC(x) +xC'(x)}{x^2 C^2(x)} $$
Substituting to $ - xz' - z = 1 $

$$ -x \frac{-C(x) - xC'(x)}{x^2C^2(x)} - \frac{1}{xC(x)} = 1 $$
$$ \frac{C'(x)}{C^2(x)} = 1 $$
$$ \frac{-C'(x)}{C^2(x)} = -1 $$
$$ (\frac{1}{C(x)})' = -1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{C(x)} = -\int1dx$$
$$ \frac{1}{C(x)} = -x+c$$
$$C(x) = \frac{1}{-x+c}$$
$$z=\frac{c-x}{x}$$
$$ y = \frac{x}{c-x}$$

than when I type it to Wolfram I get $ y(x) = \frac{-(e^{c_1} x)}{(e^{c_1} x - 1)} $

I don't know where I made a mistake.

Comment: Isn't that the same result with $c=e^{-c_1}$?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but it didn't get me to wolframs answer.

Comment: Hem, how do you get from the second to the third line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it much too complicated.

Rewrite

$$\frac{y-xy'}{y^2}=-1=\left(\frac xy\right)'.$$

Then

$$\frac xy=c-x$$ and $$y=\frac x{c-x}.$$

---

This is compatible with Alpha's answer, with the caveat that $c<0$ is allowed.

Comment: I wanted to use Bernoulli substitution, but your solution is even better

Comment: @sswwqqaa: well, this is virtually the Bernouilli substitution (with $y^{-1}$).